# FTP client with "master password"

Tags: filezilla, redhat-enterprise-linux, scientific-linux

I'm searching for an FTP client that has a "master password" function.

So all the password stored in the FTP client software is encrypted, and if I start the FTP client it asks for a master password, after then the passwords are decrypted, so I can use the FTP client as a normal FTP client.

Desktop OS where we need this kind of function in an FTP client: Scientific Linux 6.3, so a RedHat clone

Comment: As you're using a desktop Linux OS (Scientific Linux), I'm not sure why you want the FTP client to handle the passwords -- are you using a single linux account for multiple users?  (In general that's a bad practice for any OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a product that seems to fulfill your criteria :  [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/).

This runs on Linux and supports a master password.
However, as there are both a free and pro versions, I do not know whether the free version
supports a master password.

I have never used this product, so cannot recommend it from personal experience.

Answer (score 3):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) has this feature.  I just started using it recently and so far I'm impressed.  You can use passwords or public keys.  It also supports command-line use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP says his desktop OS is Scientific Linux 6.3, so a Windows app is not gonna help him out.

Comment: Oops. Good point.

Answer (score 1):

[FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) [finally added](https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla?revision=8413&view=revision) this feature.